# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process in Golang

Tags: go, zip

The process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by another process

I can't Remover Zip file with this code ..

it's possible? extract and delete the file in one code.

**Code**

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    url := "https://230c07c8-77b2-4c0d-9b82-8c6501a5bc45.filesusr.com/archives/b7572a_9ec985e0031042ef912cb40cafbe6376.zip?dn=7.zip"
    out, _ := os.Create("E:\\experi\\1234567890.zip")
    defer out.Close()
    resp, _ := http.Get(url)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    _, _ = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
    files, err := Unzip("E:\\experi\\1234567890.zip", "E:\\experi\\1234567890")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Unzipped the following files:\n" + strings.Join(files, "\n"))
}

func Unzip(src string, destination string) ([]string, error) {

    var filenames []string

    r, err := zip.OpenReader(src)

    if err != nil {


        return filenames, err
    }

    defer r.Close()

    for _, f := range r.File {

        fpath := filepath.Join(destination, f.Name)

        if !strings.HasPrefix(fpath, filepath.Clean(destination)+string(os.PathSeparator)){
            return filenames, fmt.Errorf("%s is an illegal filepath", fpath)
        }

        filenames = append(filenames, fpath)

        if f.FileInfo().IsDir() {

            os.MkdirAll(fpath, os.ModePerm)
            continue
        }
        if err = os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(fpath), os.ModePerm); err != nil {
            return filenames, err
        }
        outFile, err := os.OpenFile(fpath,
            os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC | os.O_RDWR,
            f.Mode())
        if err != nil {
            return filenames, err
        }

        rc, err := f.Open()

        if err != nil {
            return filenames, err
        }

        _, err = io.Copy(outFile, rc)
        outFile.Close()
        rc.Close()

        if err != nil {
            return filenames, err
        }
    }
    
    removeFile()
    return filenames, nil
}


func removeFile()  {
    error := os.Remove("E:\\experi\\1234567890.zip")
    if error != nil {
        log.Fatal(error)
    }
}
```

**Output**

output text

```
2020/10/28 13:09:04 remove E:\experi\1234567890.zip: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image: output Image]

Any other way to do this same thing ?

Did I go wrong anywhere?

Help Would be Much Appreciated. Thanks in Advance. :)

Answer (score 10):

`out, _ := os.Create("E:\\experi\\1234567890.zip")` creates or truncates the file and returns you a `*File` (so the file is open).

`defer out.Close()` closes the file "the moment the surrounding function returns" ([spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)).

So at the time you call `Unzip` you have the file open. To fix this call `out.Close()` before the call to `Unzip` (and please don't assume that calls complete without error).

Comment: damn :D thanks deep down in like 2000 lines of code I had a open to put something into a zip file and that helped me out since I was so deep in the process of putting the stuff into the zip that I forgot to respect the os.Create behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

If you close using the defer, it is closed after performing up to the last line of the function. You must explicitly close the file before remove it.